# Frist few bytes of a char* are corrupted after creating it with malloc()

Tags: c, string, malloc, char-pointer, corrupt-data

Whenever I create a char* with malloc(), the first few bytes get random data, which is different every time I compile the code. In this case, I wanted to concatenate 2 char* to create 1 char*.

```
char *JoinStrings(char *str1, char *str2) {
    int length = strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1;
    char *newString = malloc(length);

    if (newString == NULL) {
        printf("malloc failed\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    newString[length] = 0; // add the 0 byte at the end

    printf("String 1: %s\n", str1);
    printf("String 2: %s\n", str2);
    printf("New String: %s\n", newString);

    strcat(newString, str1);
    strcat(newString, str2);

    printf("Joined String: %s\n", newString);
    return newString;
}
```

I will call the function using this line:

```
char *join1 = JoinStrings("Hello,", " World");
```

I would expect it to print out "Joined String: Hello, World" as the last printed message, but it instead returns this:

```
String 1: Hello,
String 2:  World
New String: p‼√ΓJ☻
Joined String: p‼√ΓJ☻Hello, World
```

I have no idea where it gets the random bytes from, and they are randomized every time I compile it.
And because it gets randomized when I compile it, here is the GCC version I'm using: gcc.exe (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project) 11.2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Malloc does not initialise the allocated memory content  to any value. As `strcat` tries to locate the end of the string to concat, anything may happen. So don't use strcat for the first but strcpy:

```
strcpy(newString,str1);
strcat(newString,str2);
```

and:

```
newString[length] = 0;
```

should be:

```
newString[length-1] = 0;
```

Last element has index `length-1`.

Comment: The last element (i.e. index)  of a string is indeed "length-1", however the location of the null-terminator is [length]... which I believe was what he was trying to provide. with            " newString[length] = 0; // add the 0 byte at the end "

Comment: @TonyB No. The number of allocated byte is `length`, all are indexed through 0..length-1. The terminator NUL char must be in one of these memory cells. Accessing a cell outside these is "Undefined behavior".

Comment: You of course are correct.  I missed the fact that "length" included the null terminator.